# Passing several json into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json

**Done: after clearing my head i found a way to complete the code without JSON so it's all good now, thank you to everyone, your time was apreciated.**

I'm still new in this world of javascript and lately I've been trying to pass some database data from php to javascript, i tried using json but it seems to do nothing:

PHP code (sorry for the words in portuguese):

`

```
//info cores
$cor_sel=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM cor");
$cor_sel->execute();
$data_cor=$cor_sel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


//info tipo Vestuário
$vest_sel=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tipo_vestuario");
$vest_sel->execute();
$data_vest=$vest_sel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


//info tipo extra
$extra_sel=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tipo_extra");
$extra_sel->execute();
$data_extra=$extra_sel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


//info tipo refeição
$ref_sel=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tipo_refeicao");
$ref_sel->execute();
$data_ref=$ref_sel->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


json_encode(array('modalidade' => $data_mod, 'cariz' => $data_cariz, 'cor' => $data_cor, 'vest' => $data_vest, 'extra' => $data_extra, 'ref' => $data_ref));`
```

Javascript (different file):
The $.getJSON function is included in `$(document).ready(function() {` and the code before and after this function is working. I am testing the function now with `console.log('test');`, with no success.

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost/Rot.Aventura/eventos/criar.php', function(data) {
   console.log('test');
});
```

I've been trying to make this code work for two days, wandering on websites and trying new codes, but I can't understand it.

I apreciate the time you take to help me.

Edit: Changed the code to match the one given by GHugo and wumm but it still won't work.

Edit 2: After some tests I understood that the javascript isn't entering the $.getJSON function

Edit 3: Probably $.getJSON is not the problem, but still can't find the error

Comment: There's a `'` missing in the second line in your JS.

Comment: Ups my bad, but that wasnt the problem

Comment: The PHP code is the file `criar.php`, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is, I imagine it can be the url problem but i've tried every possibility I can think of.

Comment: What does your `alert(mod);` output?

Comment: I was trying to test if it was going into the function and at the same time trying to see if i could reach the data. After some tests I realized that it's not even entering the function

Comment: There is no way to tell why it wouldn't enter the `getJSON` function because you haven't provided any information about what function it is in or how that function is called. (That is, assuming you are actually talking about the `getJSON` function and not the anonymous function you pass to it as the second argument)

Comment: Sorry about that will edit now, I am talking about the $.getJSON function, already removed the `var mod = data['modalidade'];
    alert(mod);` so it doesn't mislead

Comment: What does your JavaScript error console say?

Comment: Being inside of `$(document).ready(function() {` shouldn't be called as soon as the page loads?
Console simply doesn't write it

Comment: Yes. Is the ready function called? What does your JavaScript error console say?

Comment: I'll edit this comment to show you the main code of document ready:
 
`$(document).ready(function() {
//some code                                                        
    console.log('test1');
        
    $.getJSON('http://localhost/Rot.Aventura/eventos/criar.php', function(data) {
        console.log('test2');                                  
    });
    console.log('test3');
});`
**Console log:**
`test1
test3`

Comment: It is showing *test3*, since that is after the `getJSON` call, there is no possible way that it could fail to enter the `getJSON` function.

Comment: Take a look at developer tool's network tab, you'll have to make sure that your request is sent correctly and received correctly. If there is no errors then try to load php file directly. If it is working then dig into js.

Comment: Are you certain you don't mean that it is failing to enter the anonymous function you pass to `getJSON` as the second argument? That is the function with *test2* in it.

Comment: Look at your browser's developer tools. Reload the page. What does the JavaScript console say? Can you see your Ajax request in the Net tab? Is it formatted correctly? Does it get a response? Is the response correct?

Comment: In google chrome I press f12 -> Network -> Select the .js -> Response: if it's that then yes i can find all the code .
@Quentin I am understanding you now, yeah it might be the function(data), but i can't understand why

Comment: No the JS, `http://localhost/Rot.Aventura/eventos/criar.php`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not being able to follow you @Quentin, do i need anything over this code like adding something to the header, or it runs fine like this?

Comment: You need to use the debugging tools in your browser to find out what is actually happening. The JavaScript error console will report any errors. The Net tab will show you if you are managing to request the URL you are asking for with Ajax and what response you are getting.

Comment: About the url if i change the `http://localhost/Rot.Aventura/eventos/criar.php` it gives me the error 404 on console

Comment: The thing is that the console is not showing the error

Comment: I've done a 'print_r($_GET)' and the result is Array( ), does this mean that its not sending anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can put your data inside an associative array:

```
// At the end of your PHP code (and remove previous echo)
echo json_encode(array('modalidade' => $data_mod, 'cariz' => $data_cariz, 'cor' => $data_cor, 'vest' => $data_vest, 'extra' => $data_extra, 'ref' => $dataref));
```

Within your javascript code you then can access each object:

```
data['modalidade']
data['cariz']
```

Comment: easier: `data.modalidade`, `data.cariz` :D